# How can I get my scanner to read the next line in the file?

Tags: java, file, input, token

I am printing out the contents of a txt file while skipping over any numbers that are in the file.

The file I am using looks like this:

one two 3 three four

five six 7 eight

I have tried using input2.next() or input2.nextline() after System.out.print(token), but I either get an error or it doesn't read the next line accurately.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class ScannerClass {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    System.out.print("Enter file name and extension: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    File file = new File(input.next());

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(file);


    String token;

//this will print out the first line in my txt file, I am having trouble
//reading the next line in the file!

    while ((token = input2.findInLine("[\\p{Alpha}\\p{javaWhitespace}]+")) != null) {
        System.out.print(token);


    }

  }
}
```

The output is:

one two  three four

What I would like to see is the whole txt file less any numbers such as:

one two  three four

five six  eight

Comment: Something like `input2.nextLine()` after your print should work

Comment: I've tried that and it ends up going to the next line as soon as it hits a number and skips the rest of that line. Am I using this [\\p{Alpha}\\p{javaWhitespace}]+ correctly?

Comment: Definitely something wrong with your regex

Comment: It is not something I am very familiar with, I am trying to read all letters and whitespaces - skipping over any numbers

Comment: The second line in the file is empty as it looks and if that is the case `findInLine` will return false and exit the loop. I would read one line at a time and do the evaluation inside the loop.

Comment: Second line is not empty, that is a formatting error on my part

Answer (score 1):

One main problem with your reg exp is that it matches only one part of the line first before the digit and then after the digit while the `findInLine` somehow advances the line counter.

So here is a different solution using your reg exp pattern but I have separated the reading from the file from the matching logic

```
Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[\\p{Alpha}\\p{javaWhitespace}]+");
while (input2.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input2.nextLine();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.print(m.group()); //Prints each found group
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this does work, however I am not very familiar with what is going on with the whole matcher and pattern stuff so I am going to spend some time looking into it. Anything you can shed light on would be fantastic!

Comment: Well Pattern is as the name suggest the class holding the pattern and performing the search while Matcher holds the result. I think the second class takes the most time to understand but two key methods are `find` that will return true as long as there is another match and `group` that holds the string that has matched the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this RegEx;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ScannerClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       System.out.print("Enter file name and extension: ");
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
       reader = new Scanner(new File(reader.next()));

       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_]+");
       Matcher m = null;

       while (reader.hasNext()){
          String nextLine = reader.nextLine();
          m = p.matcher(nextLine);
          while(m.find()) {
              System.out.printf("%s ",m.group());
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most optimum but it'll work. Each loop iteration will split the current line into an array of strings delimited by a number (`\\d+`), then each array element (the alphabet words and whitespace in this case) will be streamed and joined into a single string.

```
while (input2.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] nonNumbers = input2.nextLine().split("\\d+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(nonNumbers).collect(Collectors.joining()));
}
```